# How can I delete an inaccessible folder on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, permissions

I have a folder on one of my hard drives, `P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src\Keystone`, which I want to delete but cannot. I have tried numerous different ways to change/reset permissions and I still cannot delete this folder.

```perl
PS P:\csharp\aperture> whoami
azuread\mikelloyd

PS P:\csharp\aperture> rm -Recurse -Force .\keystone\
rm : Cannot remove item P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src: The directory is not empty.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm -Recurse -Force .\keystone\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (src:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
rm : Cannot remove item P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\: The directory is not empty.
At line:1 char:1
+ rm -Recurse -Force .\keystone\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\:DirectoryInfo) [Remove-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveFileSystemItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS P:\csharp\aperture> rmdir .\keystone\

Confirm
The item at P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\ has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you want to continue?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"): A
rmdir : Access to the path 'P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src\Keystone' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ rmdir .\keystone\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\:String) [Remove-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

PS P:\csharp\aperture> icacls.exe .\keystone\ /reset /T
processed file: .\keystone\
processed file: .\keystone\src
.\keystone\src\Keystone: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 1 files
```

I don't have read privileges.

[image: no read privileges]

It can't show the owner:

[image: no owner]

If I try to change the owner, I don't have permission to view or edit the object:

[image]

What is really strange is that I created the folder with my user, so I should be the effective owner. I have tried to delete the user as Administrator, but I can't do that either. I can't even delete the folder as `NT\System`:

```
P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src>whoami /user

USER INFORMATION
----------------

User Name           SID
=================== ========
nt authority\system S-1-5-18

P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src>rmdir /S Keystone
Keystone, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
Access is denied.
```

[image: nt system authority]

How can I delete this folder that I created?

Comment: You forgot to mention what sort of "drive" this is?

Comment: It's a local hard drive, formatted as NTFS.

Comment: What's the Azure AD stuff about, then?

Comment: P: is definitely a local drive? And your account is definitely a local admin account? And you can’t take ownership of the folder? That’s your real requirement: you want to take ownership. Once you’ve done that everything else should be easy.

Comment: My user is set up through AzureAD (I own that system).

`P:` is a local drive, I have local admin privileges (and can log in as Administrator), and I cannot take ownership. I've tried to take ownership as Administrator as well, I can't do that either.

Comment: If the problem is really just permissions, robocopy might help, see [this old answer](https://superuser.com/a/423821/96662).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this:
First, check if your User Account is Administrator.
Run cmd as administrator, 
type in `takeown /f P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src\Keystone` , this should give you ownership of the directory.
lastly, type `rmdir /q /s P:\csharp\aperture\keystone\src\Keystone`
if it still doesn't work, try the same steps in Safe Mode. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to unlockme:
UnlockMe is a freeware app to delete, move, or rename files or folders that are locked by another process.

https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/unlockme.html